# Using bash to receive UDP packet payloads with source address and port?

Tags: linux, bash, networking, udp, tcpdump

I need to listen for UDP packets, which could come from any address and any port to my listening UDP ports.

In my bash script I need to take action based on, the source address, the source port and the payload text.

I have to use bash because of memory limitation and coding ability on my part.

I initially used ncat to receive the payload for instance

```
ncat  -ul 8787
```

The problem with this is, once netcat has received a packet from one source ip address and port, it will not receive packets from other source addresses or ports.

Another problem is that netcat doesn't print the source IP and port of each packet, which I also need.

Another alternative is using tcpdump

For instance

```
tcpdump -n udp port 8787
```

Will output one line per packet

```
04:31:35.934203 IP 1.1.1.1.8787 > 192.168.2.102.8787: UDP, length 5
```

Includes source IP and port, but not the payload

Another configuration

```
tcpdump -lnA  udp port 8787


04:28:06.140486 IP 1.1.1.1.8787 > 192.168.2.102.8787: UDP, length 5
E(.!S.@...N........f"S"S....test
(............
04:28:08.798009 IP 1.1.1.1.8787 > 192.168.2.102.8787: UDP, length 5
E(.!Y.@.......~....f"S"S....test
(............
```

This prints all I need, but parsing all that excess gibberish in bash seems infeasible to me. I don't know all possible ways UDP packets can be interpreted, it seems I would need to write an entire UDP decoder stack to use this. (unless I put a ugly hack)

Yet another tcpdump command line

```
tcpdump -lnxA  udp port 8787
```

This one produces a more verbose, but cleaner, all hexadecimal output out the whole packet

```
04:27:48.580050 IP 1.1.1.1.8787 > 192.168.2.102.8787: UDP, length 5
        0x0000:  4528 0021 5301 4000 2e11 4f06 17ea cfa4
        0x0010:  c0a8 0266 2253 2253 000d 1eb7 7465 7374
        0x0020:  0a28 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
04:27:57.215598 IP 2.2.2.2.8787 > 192.168.2.102.8787: UDP, length 5
        0x0000:  4528 0021 5e0f 4000 2e11 e6e5 c694 7e0c
        0x0010:  c0a8 0266 2253 2253 000d c1a4 7465 7374
        0x0020:  0a28 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Does an easier alternative exist, again, in bash, to receive the source ip address, source port and text payload for each UDP packet I receive on that UDP port ?

Thanks

Comment: please post your UDP protocol spec or it's not easy to answer your question.

Comment: Bash is not an appropriate choice for this project. Perl or python or the like...

Comment: Hello,@Shawn Bash is what I have available. I might be able to enable bash network capabilities but I don't know how to use them. @pynexj there is no protocol, this is strictly about extracting the payload text from a series of UDP packets

Comment: the payload is binary data or plain text? line oriented or just byte stream? anyway tcpdump is a solution since it can dump all data and then you can do whatever you like with the dumped data.

Comment: The payload is just printable text. As I specified in the question, tcpdump -lnA will dump the entire packet to the stdout, the problem is that it is the entire packet, not just the payload.